# Why is the row height different when using grid-template-areas with 2 rows vs 4?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm getting a surprising behavior using grid-template-areas that I don't understand. You can see in the following CodePen a layout using 4 rows:

https://codepen.io/ericcarl/pen/dyeZzjP

[image: A 4 row layout using grid-template-areas.]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
  <p class="description">Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas:
    'title item1'
    'description item1'
    'description item2'
    'description item3';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  width: 640px;
}
h3 {
  grid-area: title;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: item2;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: item3;
}
.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}
.item1, .item2, .item3 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Everything works as desired, specifically the way the height of the "Title" grid cell is determined by its content.

But in this version that uses 2 rows, the height of the "Title" and "Paragraph" rows is different:

https://codepen.io/ericcarl/pen/rNvYzbR

[image: A 2 row layout using grid-template-areas.]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <p class="description">Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas:
    'title item1'
    'description item1';
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  width: 640px;
}
h3 {
  grid-area: title;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}
.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}
.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 400px;
}
```

The "Title" grid row is now 50% of the total grid height, rather than being determined by its contents. Why does this change when using 2 rows instead of 4? How could I get the 2-row version to have the "Title" cell's height determined by its content?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going into the minutiae of the track sizing algorithm, [Section 11.5 of the Grid specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#algo-content) says

> 11.5. Resolve Intrinsic Track Sizes
>
> This step resolves intrinsic track sizing functions to absolute
> lengths. **First** it resolves those sizes based on items that are
> contained wholly within a single track. **Then** it gradually adds in the
> space requirements of **items that span multiple tracks, evenly
> distributing the extra space across those tracks** insofar as possible.

In the first case, the title spans only one track, so its height is set and fixed, and all the free space is allocated to the description because it spans multiple tracks.

In the second case, the title and description both span a single track, so the space is divided evenly between them.

---

As far as getting the 2-row version to have the "Title" cell's height determined by its content, as UmairFarooq already says. you'd need to define the heights of the two tracks. I'd go with `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas:
    'title item1'
    'description item1';

  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  width: 640px;
}
h3 {
  grid-area: title;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}
.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}
.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <p class="description">Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! It seems obvious now, but I wasn't thinking about explicitly defining the heights. This solves it for me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the row size as well..

`grid-template-rows: 0.3fr 1.7fr;` first row will take 0.3fr and bottom row will be 1.7fr

```css
.container {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 0.3fr 1.7fr; 
  gap: 10px 10px; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "title item1"
    "description item1"; 
}

h3 {
  grid-area: title;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: item1;
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 2em;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <p class="description">Paragraph</p>
</div>
```